# Execute (sub)commands in secondary shell/command on SSH server in Paramiko

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh, paramiko

My goal is to be able to SSH into a device, execute CLI command which will take me to another Shell where I can enter in my commands. Currently, I am able to successfully SSH into a device, but cannot figure out how to get to that secondary shell with the CLI. My code below

```
import datetime, logging, os, paramiko, re, scp, sys, time, socket, logging

SSH = paramiko.SSHClient()
SSH.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
SSH.connect(server, username=usr, password=password, port=22, timeout=2)
print('successful ssh')
stdin, stdout, stderr = SSH.exec_command('cli console',bufsize=2)
# inBuf = stdout.readlines()
# for line in inBuf:
    # print(line.strip('\n'))

SSH.close()
```

My initial assumption is that after executing the cli to get into the shell console, I would be able to just simply execute whatever command I want but that is not the case. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: This really depends on the device, or rather, its SSH server implementation. It may not support `exec_command()` at all; does `ssh your-device 'cli console'` work, or do you need to run `ssh your-device` and then run `cli console` after?

Comment: If the latter, then this is probably a job for `pexpect`. See [`paramiko-expect`](https://github.com/fgimian/paramiko-expect) for some glue that may make this easier.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I read some documents on paramiko-expect and am not sure how it would be of much use.

Comment: The key difference is whether `exec_command()` or `invoke_shell()` is in use. **Usually**, when someone is having trouble interacting with a minimal embedded SSH server the issue is that that server doesn't support (the protocol-level functionality behind) `exec_command()` at all, but only supports `invoke_shell()`, so you need to send multiple commands over a single session -- hence needing an `expect`-style pattern-matching mechanism, rather than being able to get a channel per remote command.

Answer (score 0):

Write the commands that you want to execute in the subshell to the `stdin`:

```
stdin.write('command\n')
stdin.flush()
```