# Paramiko exec_command() not executing commands

Tags: paramiko, python-3.7

I am trying to automate router configuration with Python through Paramiko, however whenever I test a command through the exec_command function, it doesn't seem to do anything. If I enter the same commands through Putty it works though. I am fairly new to Python.

This is for configuration of a Ubiquiti Edge Router X. I've looked at answers here and some tutorials online and I think I am doing everything correctly

```
import paramiko

ip = '10.0.1.1'
user = 'ubnt'
passw = 'ubnt'
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(hostname = ip, port=22, username = user, password = passw)
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("configure")
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("set service dhcp-server shared-network-name LAN subnet 10.0.1.0/24 dns-server 4.2.2.2")
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("commit")
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("save")
output = stdout.readlines()
print(output)
```

The expected output should be that the dns server settings on my router should be changed to 4.2.2.2 but it doesn't seem to do anything. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the `set`, `commit` and `save` are actually subcommands of the `configure` command, not top-level commands.

So you need to feed them as an input to the `configure` command, not try to execute them as standalone commands (what your code is doing).

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("configure")
stdin.write("set service dhcp-server shared-network-name LAN subnet 10.0.1.0/24 dns-server 4.2.2.2\n")
stdin.write("commit\n")
stdin.write("save\n")
stdin.flush()
```

See also [Execute (sub)commands in secondary shell/command on SSH server in Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50708225/850848)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys. After a few days of googling around I found the solution. I had to put my commands in a wrapper class and paramiko worked fine after that.

Operational mode wrapper for top level commands: /opt/vyatta/bin/vyatta-op-cmd-wrapper

Configuration mode wrapper: /opt/vyatta/sbin/vyatta-cfg-cmd-wrapper

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = sshClient.exec_command('/opt/vyatta/bin/vyatta-op-cmd-wrapper configure')
stdin, stdout, stderr = sshClient.exec_command('/opt/vyatta/sbin/vyatta-cfg-cmd-wrapper begin')
stdin, stdout, stderr = sshClient.exec_command('/opt/vyatta/bin/vyatta-op-cmd-wrapper set service dhcp-server shared-network-name LAN subnet 10.0.1.0/24 dns-server 4.2.2.2')
stdin, stdout, stderr = sshClient.exec_command('/opt/vyatta/sbin/vyatta-cfg-cmd-wrapper commit')
stdin, stdout, stderr = sshClient.exec_command('/opt/vyatta/sbin/vyatta-cfg-cmd-wrapper save')
stdin, stdout, stderr = sshClient.exec_command('/opt/vyatta/sbin/vyatta-cfg-cmd-wrapper end')
```

Comment: Without your *"wrapper class"*, this answer won't help anyone.

Comment: Why post an incomplete answer? Where is the wrapper?